# add cycles with negative weights check in Floyd-Warshall

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

This is the pseudo-code for the Floyd-Warshall algorithm for shortest paths detection:
[image]

I was wondering if it would be possible to add a check that will test if there are no cycles with negative weights?

I think it is possible, but I do not know how to check.

Comment: That looks like a pseudocode for Bellman Ford, which of the two algorithms are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the sum of all negative weights in the graph.

You have a negative cycle if and only if you find a path to a weight that is below that minimum.

Comment: Hmm but what if I never take the cycle for the paths?

Comment: @Tryerouter If there is a cycle, you should find it.  And find that going around and around it will lead to an arbitrary negative value.